# cant fix error: create() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given and cant seem to fix it

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a django rest framework view set. I want to create an object based on data that is passed in with the post request. I have it setup right now to create new object with dummy data before it starts to take information from the request. I am getting the following error:

```
create() takes 1 positional argument but two were given.
```

Here is my viewset method:

```
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated))
   def create_user(self, request):
       data = {
           'version':1,
           'path':'testingpath1',
           'namespace':'testingnamespace1',
           'value':'testin value',
           'user_id':1,
           'person':request.user
       }
       return Preference.objects.create(data)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass keyword arguments to `create` method like `**data` instead of `data`.

Change `return Preference.objects.create(data)` to `return Preference.objects.create(**data)`